# How to read these 0-1 diagrams? I dont know whether the circles mean 0 or 1

Tags: homework-and-exercises, semiconductor-physics

This is a diagram for the input signal through a logic gate circuit, but im not sure whether the points where jt goes up/down signify a 0 or 1. [image]

Comment: Low is logic zero, high is logic one.